# Pagination not working for second page

Tags: php, jquery

This page loads perfectly with the query results in a table. The pagination is in place and has correctly divided the pages per number of records. There are other items on the page that have nothing to do with the table. When I try to go to the second page, I only get the header row with no other records and the other information shows up on the page as undefined index, almost like there was no query in the first place. I have searched the web for answers and I have exhausted what limited knowledge I have of fixing this problem. All I would like it to do is to paginate the query results from mysql database and refresh the table only everytime the user changes pages. I have looked at ajax and jquery to do this but cannot get a handle on what and how to implement it in my code. I can understand about the page refreshing problem but I would have assumed the pagination would work anyways. Below is the code that I have if anyone can point out any errors or suggest how best to make this work I would greatly appreciate it.

```
$brandname = $_GET['brandname'];
$picked = $_GET['picked'];
$pickcheck = $_GET['pickcheck'];


$brands =($brandname);
$_SESSION['$brandname']= $brandname;
$pick =($picked);
$_SESSION['$picked']= $pick;
$picker =($pickcheck);
$_SESSION['$pickcheck']=$picker;

$tbl_name="pickme";
$adjacents = 3;

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM tirestock";
$total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
$total_pages = $total_pages["num"];

$targetpage = "connecttest.php";    //your file name  (the name of this file)
$limit = 5;                                 //how many items to show per page
$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$page=mysql_real_escape_string($page);
$page = $_GET['page'];
if($page)
    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          
else
    $start = 0;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tirestock LIMIT $start, $limit";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if ($page == 0) $page = 1;
$prev = $page - 1;
$next = $page + 1;
$lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);
$lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;

$pagination = "";
if($lastpage > 1)
{
    $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";

    if ($page > 1)
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\">« previous</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">« previous</span>";

    //pages
    if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))
    {
        for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
        {
            if ($counter == $page)
                $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
            else
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";
        }
    }
    elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))
    {

        if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))
        {
            for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";
        }

        elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
        {
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";
        }

        else
        {
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";
            }
        }
    }


    if ($page < $counter - 1)
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">next »</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next »</span>";
    $pagination.= "</div>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of redundant code so I would clean it up first to see if it has anything to do with the problem.

**First problem:** There are too many assigments and checks on `$page`

```
$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$page=mysql_real_escape_string($page);
$page = $_GET['page'];
if($page)
    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          
else
    $start = 0;

if ($page == 0) $page = 1;
```

for example should just be:

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? max((int)$_GET['page'], 1) : 1;
$start = ($page - 1) * $limit;
```

Now you don't have to check if it's set, 0, etc.

**Second problem:** I don't see where you are using your other `$_GET` or `$_SESSION` variables, but if you want to retain them through your pagination, you have to add them in the pagination urls or not overwrite the session with emtpy `$_GET` variables if none are set.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have started to clean up the redundant code as you suggested. The $_GET or $_SESSION variables are used just below the code I posted and are like this:

Comment: The code is to remind the user what they picked.                  echo "<div style='font-weight:bold' text-align:center;><font size='5'>You picked Brand: $brandname<br></br></hr></div>";
 echo "<div style='font-weight:bold'><font size='5'>You picked Size: $picked<br></br></hr></div>";
 echo "<div style='font-weight:bold'><font size='5'>You picked Type: $pickcheck<br></br></hr></div>";

Comment: How do I refer to the $_GET AND $_SESSION VARIABLES by adding them into the pagination urls?

Comment: @Urob About your last question, you can add all required variables (`get` or `session`) to an array `$query`, add the page number to that array and build the query string using `http_build_query`. And where you use `"$targetpage?page=...\"` you now have to use `"$targetpage?$query\"`.

Comment: @Urob But you need to get the query and pagination to work without any additional variables first...

Comment: Thank you jeroen. I appreciate the help. I will do that and hope that fixes the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 

if($nume > $limit ){ // Let us display bottom links if sufficient records are there for paging

/////////////// Start the bottom links with Prev and next link with page numbers /////////////////
echo "<table align = 'center' width='50%'><tr><td  align='left' width='30%'>";
//// if our variable $back is equal to 0 or more then only we will display the link to move back ////////
if($back >=0) { 
print '<a href="'.$page_name.'?start='.$back.'&sex='.$field.'&searching=yes&find='.$find.'"><font face="Verdana" size="2">PREV</font></a>'; 
} 
//////////////// Let us display the page links at  center. We will not display the current page as a link ///////////
echo "</td><td align=center width='30%'>";
$i=0;

$l=1;

for($i=0;$i < $nume;$i=$i+$limit){
if($i <> $eu){
echo '<a href="'.$page_name.'?start='.$i.'&sex='.$field.'&searching=yes&find='.$find.'"><font face="Verdana" size="2">'.$l.'</font></a> ';
}
else { echo "<font face='Verdana' size='4' color=red> ".$l."</font>";}        /// Current page is not displayed as link and given font color red

$l=$l+1;
}

echo "</td><td  align='right' width='30%'>";
///////////// If we are not in the last page then Next link will be displayed. Here we check that /////
if($this1 < $nume) { 
print '<a href="'.$page_name.'?start='.$next.'&sex='.$field.'&searching=yes&find='.$find.'"><font face="Verdana" size="2">NEXT</font></a>';} 
echo "</td></tr></table>";

}// end of if checking sufficient records are there to display bottom navigational link. 
}  

?>
```

Comment: try with this one:<a href="'.$page_name.'?start='.$next.'&sex='.$field.'&searching=yes&find='.$find.'"><font face="Verdana" size="2">NEXT</font></a>'